# How to implement side effect on observable property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I relativly new in Mobx and I need automaticaly call a function when this observable array is update. 
The observable array :

```
 @observable Todos = []
```

I've many function to manage this array (addToso, removeTodo, ...) and I would like to avoid having to call this function in each of the functions that update this array.

For exemple :

```
@action addTodo(todo, important) {
  const newTodo = {
   id : Math.random(), 
   text : todo,
   isImportant : important,
   completed : false,
   date : Date.now()
  }
  this.Todos.push(newTodo)
}
```

I want when `Todos` is update a function automaticaly run for save `Todos` in my database.

```
const UpdateDbData = (id, newTodos) => {
 firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).update({
   todos : newTodos
 })
.catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Here `newTodo` is for the current value of the `Todos` array (id for the user id)

I've test with `autorun` and `reaction` but I dont understand how use them properly.

How can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `autorun`, but make sure to make the MobX observable array into a regular array with `slice`:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pibupuqove/edit?js,console))**

```
class TodoStore {
  @observable todos = [];

  constructor() {
    autorun(() => {
      const newTodos = this.todos.slice();

      firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).update({
        todos : newTodos
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    })
  }

  @action addTodo(todo, important) {
    const newTodo = {
     id : Math.random(), 
     text : todo,
     isImportant : important,
     completed : false,
     date : Date.now()
    };

    this.todos.push(newTodo);
  }
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore();

setTimeout(() => {
  todoStore.addTodo('A todo', true);

  setTimeout(() => todoStore.todos[0].text = 'A changed todo', 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats work but the `autorun` react on every change on all observables properties not only on `todos` array. I'll test `observe` later today. Nevertheless I can use the autorun property for later .

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `mobx.observe` method: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#observe.

you can use it the following:

```
constructor(){
  mobx.observe(this.Todos, (change) => {
   // update your backend data here.
   doSomething(this.Todos);
  })
}
```

this method is only trigged on todos array change. not on any other properties being changed.

notes:

- You could extract the method so you can easily make it execute on different properties (just use mobx.observe on other properties)
- If there are a lot of changes you can wrap the method in debounce method
- if you observe twice method gets trigged twice so debounce is handy!
- Observe methods get only called once per (trans)action. (just like autorun).